# UtteranceProgressListener not working for Android TTS

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am making an app that uses tts to synthesize wav files every time a broadcastreceiver is triggered. Im working on AndroidStudio (latest) and using API level 19 with min 15.

I have a Service with a BroadcastListener. Every time the BroadcastListener onReceive method is executed, I use

`tts.synthesizeToFile(playing, null, storagePath + "/" + "tst.wav");`

The file is created successfully, but the onDone() method of the UtteranceProgressListener is never called.

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Get TTS capabilities
    //TODO: Use TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA to check if tts is available
    tts = new TextToSpeech(PresenterService.this,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {

                    //If the TTS engine was started successfully

                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                        tts.setPitch(PRESENTER_PITCH);
                        tts.setSpeechRate(PRESENTER_RATE);
                    }

                }
            });

    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new TtsUtteranceListener());



    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    mReceiver = new TrackChangedReceiver(tts);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
```

And the TtsUtteranceListener class:

```
public class TtsUtteranceListener extends UtteranceProgressListener {

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("TtsUtteranceListener", "utterance Done: " + utteranceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("TtsUtteranceListener", "utterance Start: " + utteranceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("TtsUtteranceListener", "utterance Error: " + utteranceId);
    }
}
```

The method on the listener:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action != null) {
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")) {
            String playing = "test string";
            tts.synthesizeToFile(playing, null, storagePath + "/" + "tst.wav");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using AndroidStudio, and with the debug mode I can see that the mUtteranceProgressListener of the tts object has some object reference:

```
com.example.android.ttstest.TtsUtteranceListener@41eaf8d8
```

but the methods of the listener are never called. The  Log.d() calls never work and any breakpoints there are never triggered.

I also tried by declaring the UtteranceProgressListener as an anonymous class when calling

```
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener(){...});
```

but same thing...

Can someone point me in what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think I have solved it. I tried with tts.speak and the callback worked. That was my prevoius implementation. I just needed to pass a parameters HashMap with KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID parameter in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The problem was that I failed to pass the `KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID`.

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")) {
    HashMap<String, String> hashTts = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashTts.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "id");

    String playing = "test string";
    tts.synthesizeToFile(playing, hashTts, storagePath + "/" + "tst.wav");
}
```

I was passing the parameter parameter as null:

```
tts.synthesizeToFile(playing, null, storagePath + "/" + "tst.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a wired solution for detecting weather tts has finished speaking. Although it is not optimized but works well.

Step 1: Create this class in your code. (In same code, not separate file)

```
class Waiter extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            while (tts.isSpeaking()){
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch (Exception e){}
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //TTS has finished speaking. WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
        }
    }
```

Step 2: Call it when calling tts.speak(...)

```
tts.speak(...);
new Waiter().execute();
```